# How to get out of circular select?

Tags: selection-tools

I was following a tutorial video on YouTube on how to make a coffee cup, but in the middle of doing so I accidentally changed which type of selection I was using. For example I can usually drag a rectangle over object and it will select the faces, but now it's a circle and I have to run it over each face individually. I've tried googling the answer but nothing that I found has worked. Does anyone know how to get out of this?

Comment: I think you mean the **W** key - Pressing it cycles through selection modes. Keep pressing until you see an arrow surrounded by a boxed dotted line (box select - default) in the top left (in the toolbar).

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much.